# Automatic report after test in TestCafé Studio

Tags: testing, automated-tests, devops, testcafe, test-results

Is it possible to set the TestCafé Studio so that after a test run an automatic report in the desired format (for me e.g. Xunit) is exported?

The summarized reports that can be manually exported from the view would be great for my DevOps purposes if they could somehow be automatically exported after the test was completed! The report.json file in the Test-CaféStudio directory is unfortunately less helpful for my purposes.

I have already been told that it is not possible to call the software via cmd in another question. But I think in the context of the DevOps tests it should at least be possible to create automatic reports with it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no automatic export option. However, you can take any existing reporter plug-in (they are all open-source and hosted on Github) and create your own custom reporter that will do what you want. TestCafe Studio will find your custom reporter and use it.

Refer to the [Reporter Plugin](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/extend-testcafe/reporter-plugin.html) topic to learn how to create your own reporter plug-in.